# Sampling audio levels with OpenAL

Tags: ios, audio, openal

Is it possible to sample the audio playback volume in real-time with OpenAL? Specifically, I'm using OpenAL in the iPhone SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Sample audio playback volume in real-time? Are you meaning loading a sound on real time upon demand? If that's the case, you can, but there may be a delay for loading the sound.

For OpenAL samples on iPhone, I suggest you this: http://github.com/zoul/Finch

Answer (score 0):

You can set the audio playback volume for your samples by setting gain on your sources like this:

```
alSourcef (sourceID, AL_GAIN, volume)
```

where `volume` is a float value of gain between 0.0f and 1.0f.